# Magento2: magento rest api not triggering my custom plugin and observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, rest-api, plugin

I have created an observer "checkout_cart_save_before" and plugin Addproduct.

It is working perfectly for the website but not triggering for API while hitting on the postman.

Any suggestions about how to make this work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The event **checkout_cart_save_before** is only fire maegnto frontent.

You can use `sales_quote_product_add_after` event which is for all area **Frontend,Admin,Rest Api,Rest Soap**.

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_quote_product_add_after', ['items' => $items]);
```

See the class `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::addProduct`

Comment: Thanks Amit, working on it

Comment: Hi Amit, I am not able to get the current customer quote item while hitting from rest API. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: You donot get customer  in response of  API and  which API you are  using?

Comment: Hi Amit, I am using addproduct API (POST <host>/rest/default/V1/products). Here want I am trying to achieve is while adding product I am clearing the existing customer cart item, for this I am using class \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::addProduct (around plugin)